# Three.js - transparent material on one side, but showing background, not inner sides

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would to apply a transparent material on front-side faces of a geometry. It's quite easy:

```
var normal = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
            normal.side = THREE.BackSide;
    var materials = [
                normal,
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { transparent: true, opacity: 0 } )
            ];

    for( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++ ) {
                geometry.faces[ i ].materialIndex = 0;
            }
    //a 'hole' to look inside
            geometry.faces[ 0 ].materialIndex = 1;
            geometry.faces[ 1 ].materialIndex = 1;
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
```

Codepen to example above: http://codepen.io/pyort/pen/egqbLY

But there is a catch: when looking on a front-side of a face, I would like to show what's underneath this geometry, not back-side.

I'm not sure how to explain that in easy language, here is visual explanation [image]

What is my goal is this kind of 'portal' thing, so when you look from one side, it appears to have depth, but from other angles it's look super thin. How to achieve such an effect? Use some kind of shader? Use mirror techniques?

Thanks.

Comment: The solution is to use `material.colorWrite = false;` and make sure the face is rendered first so the depth buffer will prevent anything behind from being rendered. This is very tricky as you have implemented it. Experiment, instead, with a single plane and some objects behind it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment @WestLangley! What do you mean by experimenting with single plane? Switching from single geometry to multiple planes?

Comment: I do not understand what your exact problem statement is, so I cannot provide detailed advice. Get something simple to work so you understand what is going on, and then build on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
// the inside of the hole
let geometry1   = new THREE.CubeGeometry(2,2,2);
let material1   = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    transparent : true,
    color: 0xff0000,
    side: THREE.BackSide
}); 

mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material1 );
scene.add( mesh1 );

// the invisibility cloak (box with a hole)
let geometry0 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2,2,2);
geometry0.faces.splice(4, 2); // make hole by removing top two triangles

let material0 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    colorWrite: false
});

let mesh0 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry0, material0 );
mesh0.scale.set(1,1,1).multiplyScalar(1.01); // slightly larger than inside cube
scene.add(mesh0);
```

Live examples are at https://stemkoski.github.io/AR-Examples/